# How do I find out if I have an answer to a question I post?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

How do I find out if I have an answer to a question I post?

I have posted 2 questions. One was tagged as too vague, the other seems to have disappeared.

I am trying to get some traction on Ubuntu, but everything is obscure, even the question forum.

Comment: Create an account on this website, and then log into it when you want to check whether people have replied. You'll get notifications whenever anyone responds.

Comment: Do you have a link to the questions you've asked?

Answer (score 1):

If one of your questions was flagged as 'Too Vague' and closed, it will still show up on your profile, with [closed] appended to the end.

If one of your questions was downvoted a lot, it'll kind of autohide itself.  You should still be able to see it [from your own profile page](https://askubuntu.com/users/74870/namretaw).

If all your questions are hidden, you wont see them.  Or if they were deleted.

As for seeing whether you have any responses, a number will show up in the top left corner surrounded by an orange circle, letting you know you have a notification/response.  Click the number, it'll open up a list of why you got that notification, you should see your question there (or at least a link to it)